# Which regex to use to convert a list of fonts in a string to an array ?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'd like to convert an string containing a list of array to a string.

**Here's the string, fonts may vary :**

```
var fonts = "['BebasNeue', 'CaviarDreams', 'MORVA', 'Mustardo']";
```

**Here's the result I want (not a string anymore) :**

```
var fontsArray = ['BebasNeue', 'CaviarDreams', 'MORVA', 'Mustardo'];
```

The double quotes will always be on the beginning and on the end, I'm using the `string.match(...)` method, but I'm having some trouble finding the right regex.

`var fontsArray = fonts.match(/w+/g);`

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably just convert the `'` to `"` and use `JSON.parse`:

```js
var fonts = "['BebasNeue', 'CaviarDreams', 'MORVA', 'Mustardo']";
var fontsArray = JSON.parse(fonts.replace(/'/g, '"'));
console.log(fontsArray);
```